# Login using facebook android

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk

i am creating login with facebook. User logins with facebook just 1 time and i need to get it's facebook userID.

There is the code i am using:

```
// Login with facebook
    public void loginFB(View view) {

        System.out.println("started");
        facebook = new Facebook(kAppId);

        facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                System.out.println("onComplete");

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        JSONObject me = null;
                        try {
                            me = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me"));
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Login with fb");
//here i should get it's user id                            
String id = me.getString("id");
                            System.out.println("id = " + id);                                                       



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            }


            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                error.getMessage();
                System.out.println("onFacebookError");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                e.getMessage();
                System.out.println("DialogError");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                System.out.println("onCancel");
            }

        });

    }

    @Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
            facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
    }
```

So i get an exception on callback to this method:

```
        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            e.getMessage();
            System.out.println("DialogError");
        }
```

And the exception:

```
com.facebook.android.DialogError: The connection to the server timed out.
```

So i should change something in the code or there are some other problem ?

Basically i need user to login just one time when he downloads an app and i need to get his user id.

Thanks.

***EDIT:***

I had added permission to internet. So the problem was with my internet. Facebook wasn't reachable.

How ever now the problem is that: 
in this line:

```
String id = me.getString("id");
```

me is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Did you modified you `AndroidManifest.xml` to allow the app to access the internet?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#xml

In the JSONObject you need to do something like this:

```
JSONObject me =  Util.parseJson((facebook.request("me"));
```

`/me`  will return a JSON object